# Qt Creator 3.3.0: Open file in project without using mouse

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm trying Qt Creator to see if it can be used as Visual Studio replacement. (seeing that Mingw 4.9 is bundled with it and has decent C++11 support and u8 strings which aren't present in VC2013).

I can't, however, find a way to open existing file in a project without using mouse. "projects" sidebar/panel(?) can be closed and opened with Alt+0, however doing that does not place input focus there, and so I can't really navigate it without clicking it with mouse first. Am I missing anything?

What I need:
Given project that has multiple files, in qt creator open file that already exist in project without using mouse. Files are initially closed (so opening them all first and then using Ctrl+Tab is not a solution). Any way to do that?

Comment: If the files already are in the project tree, you can use Alt+X to navigate to the tree. Also, you can use Ctrl+K and open them by name.

Comment: @lisyarus: That works, thanks. If you write it as answer, i'll accept it. Is this documented anywhere, by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Alt+X to navigate to the project tree.
Also, Ctrl+K allows you to open files by name (and, in fact, a lot more - just press it and you'll see all available features, including searching for classes, methods/functions, and even some git integration).

Unfortunately, I don't know where to find some docs about these shortcuts (I found them myself).